# Delete All Word Macros that are locked with a KNOWN PASSWORD

Tags: vba, passwords, project, unlock

I have VBA code that is protected and I want to distribute the file once all the code runs, however, I want to remove all the macros before I do so that the user is not prompted to "enable" macros when they open the document.

I have this code that works if the project is "unlocked" but of course it will not work if the project is not unlocked.

I want to be able to UNLOCK the project then have the code below run. Again, I know the password.

This is a unique situation in that I have quite a few pieces of code and functions that run to perform a scan of another document. I think copy the results of the scanned document that includes comments and highlighted text into the existing document that contains all the code. I then want to remove all traces of itself so that the saved document contains no VBA or Macros.

```
Private Sub NothingHere(objDocument As Object)
' deletes all VBProject components from objDocument
' removes the code from built-in components that can't be deleted
' use like this: RemoveAllMacros ActiveWorkbook ' in Excel
' or like this: RemoveAllMacros ActiveWorkbookDocument ' in Word
' requires a reference to the
' Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library
Dim i As Long, l As Long
    If objDocument Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    i = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    i = objDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i < 1 Then ' no VBComponents or protected VBProject
        MsgBox "The VBProject in " & objDocument.Name & _
            " is protected or has no components!", _
            vbInformation, "Remove All Macros"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With objDocument.VBProject
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            On Error Resume Next
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(i)
            ' delete the component
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With
    With objDocument.VBProject
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            l = 1
            On Error Resume Next
            l = .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
            .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, l
            ' clear lines
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```